# How to test the similarity between two labelled datasets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, similarities, distance-functions

I have two different functions with I can draw labelled data $(x, y)$ from, where $x$ is multi-dimensional, and $y$ is a real number value. There exist a $y$ value for any possible $x$ in the input space.

To measure the similarity of the two functions, I would like to randomly sample $n$ number of datapoints from both functions and measure their similarity as a proxy of the similarity of the underlying functions. $x$ from the two datasets are not expected to be statistically different from each other because they are drawn randomly from the entire input space. Hence methods that rely on testing the differences in distributions of $x$ will not work.

What are some appropriate methods to measure the similarity between two labelled datasets?

My current thought is to bin the datasets according to $y$ value, and within each bin, apply maximum mean discrepancy (MMD) to measure the similarity. However the problem is that the values used for binning is arbitrary.

Comment: I guess that if the $x$ values you draw are the same for both datasets, you could test for similarity of the $y$ distribution. For that, I think a Kolmogorov–Smirnov  test could work.

Comment: Thanks @Pohoua. I can draw the same $x$ values for both dataset, and obtain 2 list of $y$s. However for KS test, the order of the two list of $y$s doesn't matter, so I may obtain a high similarity measured by KS test, but in fact, the $p(y|x)$ are very dissimilar. For eg. if $f_1(x_1) = f_2(x_2)$, $f_1(x_2) = f_2(x_1)$, versus $f_1(x_1) = f_2(x_1)$, $f_1(x_2) = f_2(x_2)$. The 2nd case should be where the 2 functions are similar. But both cases would give same KS test result.

Comment: I see. Indeed just comparing the $y$ distribution could lead to wrong conclusion. 
If you draw the same $x$ for both and then get two lists of $y$, say $y$ and $y'$, why not just compare the $\sum_i (y_i - y_i')^2$ ? This could give an idea on how close the two functions are.
Maybe you could even compare this sum of square to some distribution you can obtain by monte carlo...

Comment: @Pohoua, thanks for your suggestions, I think comparing the MSE would work. May I clarify what you mean by comparing the MSE with some monte carlo sampling?

Comment: Let's say you have some $x$s. Then, you generate two lists of $y$s based on these $x$ using $f_1$. You compute the MSE between these $y$s. And then you repeat that say 1000 times, in order to have a distribution of $MSE$.
Finally you can compare the MSE you got when comparing $f_1$ and $f_2$ with this distribution, and obtain some kind of $p$-value...
Would this make sense ?